# Can someone explain the difference between these two typedefs? (Function pointer related)

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef

This one is quite obviously a function pointer :

```
typedef int (* foobar) (int a, unsigned char *b, unsigned int c);
```

But what does this one do?

```
typedef int (foobar *) (int a, unsigned char *b, unsigned int c);
```

Comment: The second is simply syntactically invalid. That all there's to it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It produces a compiler error, at least in GCC 4.3:

```
foo.cpp:1: error: expected `)' before '*' token
```

Comment: The code hasn't been run yet, but it was written by an experienced coder. It's for CodeWarrior BTW.

Comment: Just confirmed that it was a mistake. Thanks y'all! :)